# Give an int table column in MySQL a range of allowed values from 1 to 9

Tags: mysql, sql, dns

I am new in MySQL and I was wondering if there is a way of giving a column a range of accepted values let's say from 1 to 9; I was trying the following but it does not work.

```
CREATE TABLE rooms (
    `rNumber` INT( 1 -9 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
    PRIMARY KEY ( `hNumber` )
)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on exactly what you are driving at you might consider using the [MySQL Enum Type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/enum.html).

Comment: If your problem is solved can you mark this question as answered? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

[ENUM and SET columns](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/constraint-enum.html) are MySQL specific.

The most capable and cross platform means of doing what you ask requires you to:

1. Create a table to contain all the values you want:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE rValidation (
      rNumber INT AUTO_INCREMENT
   )
   ```
2. Relate the appropriate column in the `rooms` table to the column to use for validation in the table created in Step 1, using a [foreign key constraint](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html)

Answer (score 2):

`CHECK` constraints are not enforced in MySQL. They are parsed during the `CREATE TABLE` statements but are ignored.

One way to enforce such a constraint is to use a `FOREIGN KEY` constraint to a reference table, which has exactly 9 rows and allowing only `SELECT` privileges to it (so nobody adds, changes or removes rows from it):

```
CREATE TABLE NineNumbers (
    i INT NOT NULL ,
    PRIMARY KEY (i)
)

INSERT INTO NineNumbers (i)
  VALUES
  (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9) ;

CREATE TABLE rooms (
    rNumber INT NOT NULL ,            --- AUTO_INCREMENT or not
                                      --- PRIMARY KEY or not
    FOREIGN KEY (rNumber)
      REFERENCES NineNumbers (i) 
)
```

Answer (score 1):

If your range doesn't include zero then an [`enum`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/enum.html) will work, MySQL reserves zero for certain error conditions:

> The index value of the empty string error value is 0.

You'll also want strict mode enabled if you really only want 1-9 in your column:

> If you insert an invalid value into an ENUM (that is, a string not present in the list of permitted values), the empty string is inserted instead as a special error value. This string can be distinguished from a “normal” empty string by the fact that this string has the numeric value 0.
>   [...]
>   If strict SQL mode is enabled, attempts to insert invalid ENUM values result in an error.

Alternatively, you could add an INSERT and UPDATE trigger that would check that the new `rNumber` was within the desired range and [raise an exception](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/signal.html) if it wasn't. This approach is more or less equivalent to a CHECK constraint in other databases.

Answer (score 0):

The check should be performed in PHP, what happens if you insert a value which is not in range it will insert a NULL value

Try this

```
$rNo=$_POST['rNumber'];
if($rNo >=1 && $rNo <=9)
{
// Execute Insert query
}
else
{
//display error message saying value not in range
}
```

Comment: Whatever PHP sends to the database, a `NULL` cannot be inserted into a `NOT NULL` column.

Comment: No, that is a bad design, data integrity should be done on the database, so it can be separated from the application and work well without PHP and Apache on a server dedicated only to the database on a larger scaled application. I made this mistake before and now I regret it.